# asp.net freeze background page with loading popup

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is my ASPX code

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <style type="text/css">
    .image1
    {
        top:100;
    }
    #dvLoading
    {

    }
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="**"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
           <class="dvLoading" style=" height:100%; top:0; width:100%; background-color: gray; opacity: 0.4; filter: alpha(opacity=40);
                        left: 0px; z-index: 999999; position: absolute; text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/load1.png" Width="146px" 
                ImageAlign="Middle" CssClass="image1" />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</asp:Content>
```

The problem is that when i compile it, all are good but my "load1.png" image is going to top of the page,
but i want that my loading image is going to center.

i am using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use jQuery plug-in [jquery.malsup.com/block/](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) for this purpose. It is very customizable and automatically works on whole page or some DOM element.

General solution for all Update panels requests:
Add reference to jQuery and http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js script and write:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(function (){
    $.blockUI();
});
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function (){
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

Or you can add call to $.blockUI() only on button ClientClick event.

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer.
thanx everyone for helping me

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="**"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
           <class="dvLoading" style=" height:100%; top:0; width:100%; background:url(load1.png) no-repeat center center,gray;
               opacity: 0.8; left: 0px; z-index: 999999; position: absolute; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; " />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</asp:Content>
```